# Compile error for passing nil to an optional parameter with a generic type constraint

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

My class `MQChainedOperation` has a function `append` which accepts any operation that inherits from `MQOperation`:

```
public func append<T: MQOperation>(operation: T, 
    validator: (Any? -> Bool)?,
    configurator: ((T, Any?) -> Void)?) {
        // ...
}
```

In a view controller, I do this:

```
let chain = MQChainedOperation()
chain.append(
    MQBlockOperation {[unowned self] in
        // ...
    },
    validator: nil,
    configurator: nil)
chain.append(
    SignUpOperation(),
    validator: nil,
    configurator: nil)
```

And the compiler throws this error at me from both calls to append, when both `MQBlockOperation` and `SignUpOperation` do inherit from `MQOperation`:

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(MQOperation, validator: (Any? -> Bool)?, configurator: ((MQOperation, Any?) -> Void)?)'
>
> Expected an argument list of type '(T, validator: (Any? -> Bool)?, configurator: ((T, Any?) -> Void)?)'

However, if I supply an empty closure for the `configurator`, it works:

```
chain.append(
    MQBlockOperation {[unowned self] in
        // ...
        return NSDate()
    },
    validator: nil,
    configurator: {(op, result) in})
chain.append(
    SignUpOperation(),
    validator: nil,
    configurator: {(op, result) in})
```

I should be able to pass `nil` to an optional parameter, and the workaround makes my code ugly. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're sure the type annotation to parameter `configurator` in the generic function `append` is exactly as it should be?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, the `configurator` should be an optional closure that accepts a tuple of type `(T, Any?)` and returns nothing. I wear glasses, but I double-checked the func signature's closing parentheses as hard as I could, and Xcode isn't complaining about any syntax errors there.

Comment: Hm, looks ok - when looking closely ;)

Comment: Looks like a bug with the Swift compiler. It's reproducible in a playground project--define a func with constraint `<T: NSOperation>` and two parameters, one of type `T` and another an optional closure that accepts `T`. Reporting to Apple.

Comment: I can only suspect that there's an issue with the type parameter `T` in parameter `configuration` - when the argument is `nil`. You should create a small sample that demonstrates this problem. -- Yes, guess it's a problem with the compiler.

Comment: BTW, you can use non-Optionals as well (for a workaround) - and set them to empty. Performance-wise, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments, this seems like a bug with the Swift compiler. For now, a quick, clean fix I like is to provide `nil` as a default value in the function signature.

```
public func append<T: MQOperation>(operation: T,
    validator: (Any? -> Bool)?,
    configurator: ((T, Any?) -> Void)? = nil)
```